# How to build libevent version 2.0.10 with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, build, libevent

Does anyone have clear instructions on building libevent-2.0.10 with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt, then

```
cd \where\you\put\it
nmake -f makefile.nmake
```

Or if you prefer the IDE, then File + New + Project, Visual C++, General node, pick the Makefile Project template.  Name = libevent-2.0.10-stable, Location = parent directory (\where\you\put).  OK.  Next.   Build command = nmake -f makefile.nmake, rest blank.

Comment: Just a note for others wanting to build libevent. Having been away from C/C++ for a long while, I made a nube assumtion that the libevent build they provided would output a libevent.dll. Instead it's examples which compile only required parts of libevent into their exe's.

Comment: But there is no nmake in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Sure there is, located in the vc\bin subdirectory.  The Express edition is special.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to run vcvars32.bat before nmake to set up the environment variables for VC.

Comment: This is unnecessary from the `Visual Studio Command Prompt`. A link which is created in the start menu when the compiler is installed.

Comment: Vcvars32.bat run on directory compiled when use cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GUI to build it, do not check the option "Create directory for solution" when creating the project.